# How to make from two methods one method in a repository

Tags: angular, linq, asp.net-core, repository

I have this two methods:

```
  private IQueryable<Alert> GetAlert(int organisationId, bool includeDone = false)
        {
            var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts
                .Where(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId);

            if (!includeDone)
            {
                query = query.Where(i => !i.IsDone);
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(i => i.Deadline);

            return query;
        }


        private IQueryable<Alert> GetAlerts(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate ,  bool includeDone = false)
        {
            var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts
                .Where(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (beginDate == null ||  i.CreatedAt <= endDate) && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate));               

            if (!includeDone)
            {
                query = query.Where(i => !i.IsDone);
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(i => i.Deadline);

            return query;
        }
```

So the only differenece is that one method has pass as parameters dateTeime for filtering.

But is it possible to make one method of this?

Thank you

This is How I use it now:

```
  public async Task<Alert> GetAlertForOrganisation(Guid alertId, int organisationId)
        {
            return await GetAlert(organisationId)
                .Where(i => i.AlertId == alertId)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAllAlertsForOrganisation(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
        {
            return await GetAlerts(organisationId, beginDate, endDate)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the whole filter as an expression parameter:

```
public IQueryable<Alert> GetAlerts(Expression<Func<Alert, bool>> filter, bool includeDone = false)
{
    var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts
        .Where(filter);

    if (!includeDone)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => !i.IsDone);
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(i => i.Deadline);

    return query;
}
```

And use it as follow:

```
var query1 = repository.GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId)
    .ToList();
var query2 = repository.GetAlerts(i =>
        i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) &&
        (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: How can I use that in my own method?